# how to remove forward slash generated from wordpress editor

Tags: php, wordpress

I have following html for a wordpress custom plugin which is loaded to a wordpress editor

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="outer">
<div class="job_details">
```

But when its saved to a database its changes as follows

```
<div class=\"container-fluid\">
<div class=\"outer\">
<div class=\"job_details\">
```

because of this slashes css styles are not getting reflecting. How to remove this slashes?. Please help

Comment: Try this stripslashes_deep. <?php
wp_editor( stripslashes($content), $editor-id );
?>

Comment: Its working now. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Try this:

stripslashes_deep. <?php wp_editor( stripslashes($content), $editor-id ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try `wp_kses_stripslashes` function. This function changes the character sequence `\"` to just `"`.

```
<?php wp_kses_stripslashes( $string ) ?>
```